# Is it possible to add a Xcode created sticker pack into a Xamarin.Forms iOS bundle for the AppStore upload?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, imessage

I want to integrate iMessage into my App. But I just need a simple Sticker Pack. The documentation of Xamarin says here "A Sticker Pack Message Apps Extensions can be created from inside of Xcode without including any code. All that is required is the assets for the stickers and the app icons.".But how do I add this Sticker Pack to my Xamarin.Forms project so that it is uploading to the AppStore with the package / bundle?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the docs is that if you just want an app that is a sticker pack (i.e. does nothing else), then don't do it in Xamarin / Visual Studio, you just fire up Xcode, create a new empty app, and add then assets and requirements for Stickers.

If (as in your case) you want Stickers as an extension to your App then you need to create a Message App extension, as per https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/message-app-integration/intro-to-message-app-extensions/#Creating_a_Custom_Sticker_Experience

Happy to be corrected, but that was my interpretation - HTH

Comment: The link you provided is not an answer to the question. Adding an iMessage app extension adds a different project and therefore a different `.ipa` file that would need to be deployed separately.